# How to configure OBS studio to have only one recording window?

Tags: obs

Since I reinstalled OBS my display has changed from having one scene recording window to having 2.
I have tried modifying every possible setting I thought off but I don't manage to get rid of the second window.
The problem is this window seems to define the screen capture area and I can't modify it. This seems only possible in the left scene frame, but doesn't have any effect on the recording. 
Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

When you open up the properties of the screen-capture, you should be able to select the screen you're trying to record. If else, please post a screenshot of it.